# Make a form date value optional

Tags: jquery, spring, forms, datatable, momentjs

In my aplication, the query results are showed using jquery Data Table.
The last task is add a date field to form search, but this value is optional for final user (as the others of form).

This is the code section where I initialize the fields with the form data:

```
DTevents = $('#eventsdata').DataTable( 
            { 
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                            url: "../getevents.json",
                            type: "post",
                            "data": function (d)
                            {
                                return $.extend(d, {typename :  $('#typename').val()}, {infoname :  $('#infoname').val()}, 
                                                {hostname :  $('#hostname').val()}, {datevalue :  moment($('#datevalue').val()).toDate().getTime() });
                            }

                       },
```

The other fields are also accepted if empty; for this, in my Spring controller, I used this code:

```
@InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
        }
```

As you can see, the date is given in input to moment.js to convert into long to pass to Controller. If I query the app without insert a value for other fields, it works perfectly (a query without value from Form is used to perform a `SELECT *` in our scenario).

But now, if I left the date empty, I obtain an empty table and a console message:

```
2017-08-23 12:32:44.870  WARN 8396 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NaN"
```

So my question is: how can I tell to my app that also the "date" field is optional?

Comment: Note that you can use [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) to get  milliseconds since the Unix Epoch from a moment object directly instead of converting it `toDate()` and then call `getTime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring controller throw the exception because he expects value of type `long`, but you pass the parameter always, also if the value of `datevalue` is blank. In this case moment function `getTimestamp` will return `NaN` (not a number) as String and the controller complaines because of the wrong type. Try to avoid send the parameter if the user doesn't insert it:

```
{
    var param = {typename : $('#typename').val(), infoname :  $('#infoname').val(), hostname :  $('#hostname').val() };

    if(moment($('#datevalue').val()).isValid()){
        param = $.extend(param, {datevalue : moment($('#datevalue').val()).toDate().getTime()});
    }

    return $.extend(d, param);

}
```

Pay attention to the `isValid` method if you don't use [standard iso date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) you have to tell moment which format you use. Example if you use `dd/MM/yyyy` format:

```
moment('23/08/2017', "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid()
```